# how to give file name a input in baby parser

Tags: node.js, csv, papaparse

I am trying to use baby parser for parsing csv file but i am getting below output if i give file name

file and code are in same directory

my code:

```
var Papa = require('babyparse');
var fs = require('fs');
var file = 'test.csv';
Papa.parse(file,{
    step: function(row){
        console.log("Row: ", row.data);
    }


});
```

Out put :

Row:  [ [ 'test.csv' ] ]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`file` must be a File object: http://papaparse.com/docs#local-files. In nodejs, you should use the `fs` API to load the content of the file and then pass it to PapaParse: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options

```
var Papa = require('babyparse');
var fs = require('fs');
var file = 'test.csv';

var content = fs.readFileSync(file, { encoding: 'binary' });
Papa.parse(content, {
    step: function(row){
        console.log("Row: ", row.data);
    }
});
```

The `encoding` option is important and setting it to *binary* works for any text/csv file, you could also set it to *utf8* if your file is in unicode.

Comment: how to convert the data to json in baby parse

Comment: Just use `var data = Papa.parse(content)`, it returns a special object: http://papaparse.com/docs#results If your csv has headers, you can get a json else you'll an array of arrays.