# unable to parse csv to json using Baby Parse

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, csv, papaparse

I am trying to use **baby parse** (branch off of Papa Parse) to take a csv file and parse the data to Json.
The csv file I am testing is very straight forward:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3
1,2,3
3,2,1
```

So far I am successfully loading the file using **ng-file-upload** to load the csv file via the browser.

I am now trying to use **baby parse** to take this file and convert the data to JSON.

Below is what I have so far:

**The controller**

```
// Watch for a csv file being uploaded.
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.file
    }, function(){
        $scope.upload($scope.file);
});

$scope.upload = function(file){
            if(file){
                Upload.upload({
                    url: 'api/admin/uploadCsv',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {userId: $scope.user._id},
                    file: file
                }).progress(function(evt){
                    console.log("firing");
                }).success(function(data){

                }).error(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                })
            }
        };
```

On file upload the upload function is called and calls the server controller.
The file uploaded is passed to the upload function which I am then attempting to pass to the parse method.

```
module.exports.uploadCsv = function(req, res){
    var file = req.files.file;
    var userId = req.body.userId;

    parsed = babyparse.parse(file.path, babyParseConfig);
    console.log("data is " + (JSON.stringify(parsed.data)));
    ...
```

The console.log outputs the following:

```
data is {"data":[],"errors":[],"meta":{"delimiter":",","linebreak":"\n","aborted":false,"truncated":false,"fields":["..\\App\\uploads\\565b8feecddbb1e41b7aa839test.csv"]}}
```

I can not understand why data:[] is empty given what the csv file looks like.

Comment: Are you sure that the contents of `file.path` on the server is the CSV file? What do you get if you read `file.path` and log its contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the answer provided here ([how to give file name a input in baby parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942491/how-to-give-file-name-a-input-in-baby-parser)), I have got the parser working. 
Below is what I ended up with:

```
   var uploadcontent = fs.readFileSync(targetPath, { encoding: 'binary' });
   var parsed = babyparse.parse(uploadcontent);
   console.log((JSON.stringify(parsed)));
```

**Note that uploadContent is the path to the directory which I am saving the file to rather than the file itself.**

The above outputs the following

```
{"data":[["Column1","Column2","Column3"],["1","2","3"],["3","2","1"]],"errors":[],"meta":{"delimiter":",","linebreak":"\r\n","aborted":false,"truncated":false}}
```

The above can be refined to something like     `console.log((JSON.stringify(parsed.data)));`
to get just data.